# Hosting a dot net forms app inside a web browser?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I already have a dot net forms (3.5) desktop app that I now need to deliver a web interface for it.

I was wondering if there is a way to just deliver the same app over the Web inside some kind of container.

Is there anything available that I can use to do this? If not what is the best way to go about building the web interface with minimum work.

Comment: So basically if I port my app to WPF it can be hosted inside a web browser ?

Comment: http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/aspnet/how-to-migrate-a-winforms-application-to-the-web-using-visual-webgui.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The two programming models are too different. If it's a simple application, you can look into [webforms on ASP.NET](http://www.asp.net/web-forms), but it still requires you to port your application for the web.